# Empty Private Key from .pfx file

Tags: ssl, iis, openssl, iis-10

So this is my case in a nutshell. So I created a "certificate signing request" (CSR) on my IIS server and sent it to another team that will send it to a certificate authority (CA) to generate get my certificate.

However, I realised that the domain I put was wrong. So I created a new (i.e. second) CSR on the IIS server and sent it to the other team. However, the other team realised that it would be easier for them if they add the correct domain as an *alternative name* instead of revoking the existing certificate and sent me that altered certificate.

So, I completed the CSR on the ISS server with that certificate. Then I **exported** the certificate+privateKey to a `.pfx` file which I copied to my local machine.

Then I ran the following commands to extract the CertBody and Private Key from the pfx file:

Extract CertBody:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in .\TestPrivateKey.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out CertBody.pem
```

Extract Encrypted PrivateKey:

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -in .\TestPrivateKey.pfx -nocerts -out PrivateKey.pem
```

Get the unencrypted PrivateKey:

```
openssl.exe rsa -in .\PrivateKey.pem -out NoPrivateKey.pem
```

The problem is that both the CertBody.pem & PrivateKey.pem are **blank** files. I suspect that the reason for that is because I created a new CSR. I am wondering if there is a way to cancel the first CSR so that I can complete the 1st CSR with the first certificate that was generated as i

Comment: First, verify the content of that .pfx file by importing it to Windows certificate store.

Comment: Thanks! Will do that as soon as I reach my work PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after installing / reinstalling openssl, they were not empty anymore.